# Target "run-ondemand" does not exist in the project

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, selenium-webdriver, command-prompt

I am fixing some bugs on the automation code using selenium 2.0 as framework. I installed ant, and I use Eclipse Juno on windows 07 64 bit. Before, making any changes on the code, I  run the script on the command prompt and on eclipse without any problem. But, since I made some changes, the script runs only on Eclipse and not anymore on the command prompt. I have tried to figure out the problem but did not come up with the answer. This is a description of what is happening:
When I type in the command prompt 'ant init', I get the following:

> init
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   total time:0 seconds

However, when I type the command line '`ant run-ondemand -Dtype=package -Dpackage.name=comMy_package.Test`', I obtain the following:

> BUILD FAILED
>   Target "run-ondemand" does not exist in the project "my_Project"
>   total time: 0 seconds.

I am new to Selenium and Ant. Does any one have any idea? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured out the solution. Eclipse changes the build.xml file every time i run the script after some changes are made on the source. The new settings generated on the build.xml file is now different from the one that was initially recognized by Ant. to avoid the problem, I just copied the original settings of the build.xml file and pasted it in the one containing the current settings. I then run the script via the command prompt and everything just works fine now. If I want to run the script with Eclipse, I will paste the settings generated by eclipse earlier, as i saved it in a text file.